# TFS is using server's hostname instead of domain name

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I've installed TFS 2012 on a remote Windows 2008 R2 Server (www.mydomain.com) which has a build controller. I created a build agent on my local machine, but my builds just stay in the queue for a long time before giving up with an error. The message says Exception Message: TF30063: You are not authorized to access http://mydomain.com:8080/tfs/defaultcollection. In Visual Studio, it names my builder controller as "myhost - Controller" where myhost is the hostname given to the Windows 2008 R2 server. The hostname is just used internally to name the machine.

EDIT:
I am not using active directory just plain local users.

Comment: how have you setup authentication between build machine and application tier?  eg active directory or using local users?

Comment: See my edit.  Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this same setup and the "workaround" i use is adding a Host record to your working machine that matches the name it is looking for to your I.P. address or actual host name. It has been working fine.

Edit host record quick google(http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/)

and put in [expected host name] [actual I.P. or hostname]

then it will resolve appropriately

Comment: I think this problem has something to do with WCF. I remember encountering the same problem with WCF using the hostname rather than the domain.